# Removing strings in array with Perl's grep

Tags: perl, grep

I have the following array:

```
$arry = [
      '',
      'foo',
      'bar',
      'ion'
    ];
```

What I want to do is to remove `""` `ion` and `bar`. 
But why this failed?

```
my @new = grep {!/ |ed|ion/} @$arry;
```

It prints:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '',
          'foo',
          'bar'
        ];
```

Test here: https://eval.in/50792

Comment: and why do you use 'ed' instead of 'bar'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
my @new = grep {!/^$|ed|ion/} @$arry;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `grep` leaves the elements `''`, `'foo'`, and `'bar'`. This is because it is removing elements that *contain* a single space, `'ed'`, or `'ion'`. Ony one element of your array matches this criterion: the last one, which is `'ion'`. So only this one is removed.

Perhaps you want

```
my @new = grep { $_ ne '' and $_ ne 'ion' and $_ ne 'bar' } @$arry;
```

or

```
my @new = grep $_ !~ /\A(?:|ion|bar)\z/, @$arry;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep words like `edition`, use :

```
my @new = grep {!/^$|\b(?:ed|ion)\b/} @$arry;
```